# Entity Reference Error when uploading profile picture

Tags: 8, files

We are getting the following error when uploading a profile picture as an authenticated user.

[image]

Drupal Version is 8.5.1. Its working fine for admin users. We don't have any permission modules installed on our site. Any idea why this error is coming?

Comment: Do you use any upload module?

Comment: No. Just the Drupal core features. No custom modules

Comment: Could you take a screen shot of the permissions page?

Comment: I updated another site to Drupal 8.5.1. Got same error there as well. Screenshot of permission from that site is attached. https://ibb.co/gkDRp7